# use output values for all images?

Tags: javascript, html, color-picker

Below javascript code update just 1 img src on my page, I have 10 to 20 images on my page. one way to do is i have paste above code multiple time and apply one by one on image . So is their any better way to do this so i can apply input values on all my images.

Test My Code : http://jsfiddle.net/3ugfzL68/5/

```js
function update() {
  let src = 'https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=657406&width=' +
    $('#size2').val().replace('#', '') + '&height=100&RenderText=' +
    $('#name').val().replace('#', '') + '&TextSize=' +
    $('#size1').val().replace('#', '') + '&TextColor=%23' +
    $('#clr1').val().replace('#', '') + '&BgColor=%23' +
    $('#clr2').val().replace('#', '');
  $('#1Img').attr('src', src);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
Font Size: <input class="textsize" id="size1" onchange="update()" value="55" size="3"> Font Color: <input class="jscolor" id="clr1" onchange="update()" name="color" value="FF0000" size="6"> Background Color: <input class="jscolor" onchange="update()"
  name="color" id="clr2" value="FFFFFF" size="6"> Width: <input class="textsize" id="size2" onchange="update()" value="355" size="4">
<input class="textsize" id="name" onchange="update()" value="[field title]" type="hidden">
<br/> Style 1: <img id="1Img" alt="Image 1" src="https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=657406&width=350&height=100&RenderText=name here&TextSize=55&TextColor=%23ff0000&BgColor=%23"> Style 2: <img id="2Img" alt="Image 2" src="https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=655506&width=350&height=100&RenderText=2nd style name here&TextSize=55&TextColor=%23ff0000&BgColor=%23">

<br/><br/>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet with the picker as a CDN include so it could be posted here

Comment: Ok Thanks for this, im new so thanks for help

Comment: And here is a fixed fiddle. You need to add the script to the left in resources and pick the jQuery from the panel dropdown http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/j1wy4mec/

Comment: ok thanks again for this, but  can we do this ? can we apply values on all images as all images different so can we provide input values to all?

Comment: Probably. If you can do one you can do all. I have not looked at the code, only the formatting

Comment: i just know only one way which is need to copy and paste code again and again for all images and update id's and other values for all images one by one . so i want to find any quick way which apply values to all images, anyways thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly do not start IDs with numbers.

But since you use jQuery you can loop and assign on each change - no need for IDs

```js
$(".control").on("change", function() {
  $(".img").each(function() {
    let src = $(this).attr(src).split("&width")[0] +
      '&width=' + $('#size2').val().replace('#', '') +
      '&height=100&RenderText=' + $('#name').val().replace('#', '') +
      '&TextSize=' + $('#size1').val().replace('#', '') +
      '&TextColor=%23' + $('#clr1').val().replace('#', '') +
      '&BgColor=%23' + $('#clr2').val().replace('#', '');
    $('#1Img').attr('src', src);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
Font Size: <input class="control textsize" id="size1" onchange="update()" value="55" size="3"> Font Color: <input class="control jscolor" id="clr1" onchange="update()" name="color" value="FF0000" size="6"> Background Color: <input class="control jscolor"
  onchange="update()" name="color" id="clr2" value="FFFFFF" size="6"> Width: <input class="control textsize" id="size2" onchange="update()" value="355" size="4">
<input class="textsize" id="name" onchange="update()" value="[field title]" type="hidden">
<br/> Style 1: <img class="img" id="Img1" alt="Image 1" src="https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=657406&width=350&height=100&RenderText=name+here&TextSize=55&TextColor=%23ff0000&BgColor=%23"> Style 2: <img class="img" id="Img2" alt="Image 2"
  src="https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=655506&width=350&height=100&RenderText=2nd+style+name+here&TextSize=55&TextColor=%23ff0000&BgColor=%23">

<br/><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for help and spend your time for this code. just need one more help can you please update this or make it on jsfiddle so i can understand batter as im new so please . thanks again

Comment: i try it but unable to work thats why i ask, any ways many many thanks to you .

Comment: I did not have any images that reacts to the changes. The code I posted should be able to run, you likely need to fix some console errors, but the idea is sound